# How to change the listSeparatorTextViewStyle color of ListView with seperators

Tags: android, listview

i have a List view with seperators, for the header i am using this xml:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_header_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />
```

By using `listSeparatorTextViewStyle` the default color is gray, how can i change that color or add an image ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create your own `style`.

The Android Source code is a best friend for quickly gathering and building system styled themes.

Follow this path from the source code you've downloaded via `Android SDK Manager`

`platforms/android-19/data/res/values`

You'll find something like this inside `styles.xml`:

For Dark theme:

```
<style name="Widget.Holo.TextView.ListSeparator" parent="Widget.TextView.ListSeparator">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/list_section_divider_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

For Light theme

```
<style name="Widget.Holo.Light.TextView.ListSeparator" parent="Widget.TextView.ListSeparator">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/list_section_divider_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

By following the path the code mentioned above, you'll get all the assets/images you need to build your own one.